# Simulate the winKey press event in android

Tags: android, events, keyboard, qwerty

I'm using a bluetooth keyboard with an android tablet and i've found that there's some shortcut avaible from a qwerty keyboard. I want to generate some of them from the code. I'm able to trigger the majority of all the key combination but I'm not able to trigger a winKey (The windows logo key on a qwerty). I've basically try every KEY CODE from android and non of them want to work.

If any one as a little hint on that subject that would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not write a quick app that overrides onKeyDown and see what code is generated when you hit the key?

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't look that the win_key can be trigerred from a service in adnroid.